# Impossible hill cipher question

Tags: hill-cipher

I've been trying to solve this question from Forouzan's book ("Cryptography And Network Security") and haven't been able to wrap my head around how to solve it.

> The plaintext “letusmeetnow” and the corresponding ciphertext
> “HBCDFNOPIKLB” are given. You know that the algorithm is a Hill
> cipher, but you don’t know the size of the key.
>
> Find the key matrix.

I inverse the 2x2 plaintext matrix and multiple with a 2x2 ciphertext matrix and take a mod 26. However, the key matrix is always in fractions, never an integer.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction / tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you find the inverse in the fractions? The inverse of it either exists or not, Did you really worked modulo 26?

Comment: I think i miscommunicated, what I mean by inverse in the fractions is that when I calculate the inverse of a 2x2 matrix, I have to divide by the determinant right? and then transpose the matrix and so on. The inverse exists because the determinant exists. I do modulo 26 after finding inverse or after multiplying plaintext matrix inverse with ciphertext matrix

Comment: Could you show your work with a good $\LaTeX$ by editing your question? I'll not write an answer, however, I'm pretty sure that Fgrieu can update their answer base on that.

Comment: $A \times A^{-1} = I$. See: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse.html

Comment: @kelalaka, thanks for this link. I went through it and im inverting the matrix just right. Ill edit my question with Latex by tonight. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Two independent ideas:

- In the Hill cipher, elements of matrices are in the ring of [integers modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) the number of characters in the alphabet used, usually $n=26$. Therefore, as long as the denominator of a fraction is coprime with $n$ (that is, for $n=26$, if the denominator is divisible neither by $2$ not by $13$), that fraction reduces to an integer modulo $n$.
  E.g. $\displaystyle\frac23\equiv18\pmod{26}$ since $2\equiv3\cdot18\pmod{26}$.
- The Hill cipher is sometime instantiated with a $3\times3$ or larger matrix.